# Получить элемент после ajax запроса

Tags: javascript, jquery

Если проблема связанная с управлением полученным элементом при помощи jquery. До отправки ajax запроса, можно получить все атрибуты элемента и влиять на него как угодно, но в теле функции success не получается получить к нему доступ. Может нужно как-то передать this в тело функции?
Привожу код:

```js
/* Events after clicking on save button */
$("table").on('click', '.glyphicon-ok', function () {
  
   var rowId = $(this).attr('id');
  
   //Здесь работает
   alert($(this).attr('id'));
        
   /* Change the icon of button */
   $(this).removeClass('glyphicon-ok').addClass('glyphicon-pencil');

        $.ajax({
            url: path,
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            data: data,
            success: function (response) {
              
           //Здесь не работает
           alert($(this).attr('id'));
              
           /* Change the icon of button */
            $(this).removeClass('glyphicon-ok').addClass('glyphicon-pencil');
            }
        });

    });
```

Нужно получить элемент полностью, так как в случае успеха аякс запроса будут меняться его атрибуты.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

сделайте вот так `var id= $(this).attr('id')` перед аяксом

а внутри success функции используйте `id`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но мне нужно получить именно this, так как мне нужно изменить его атрибуты.

Comment: так создайте таким же образом переменную и присвойте ему $(this) перед аяксом, и уже внутри него используйте новый объект

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно)